# Redefining a letter to itself

Tags: characters, catcodes

I have no idea why anyone would actually want to do this, but I want to know how I would do it (for educational purposes).

Say I make `e` and active token, and then make it print the character `e`.

I chose `e` because it is a letter in `\def`. So, here is my thought, which doesn't work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
% Now I can't use e, so I have to use something else instead. 
% I tried ^^65, but it doesn't work (65 is ASCII hex value for e)
  {
    \catcode`e=\active
    \d^^65f{\char`e}
    SomTxt
  }
\end{document}
```

This is failing because the letter `e` is inside `\def`. How would I make this compile correctly?

Comment: `\`e` would also fail if e is active

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
% Now I can't use e, so I have to use something else instead. 
% I tried ^^65, but it doesn't work (65 is ASCII hex value for e)
  {\let\z\def
    \catcode`e=\active
    \ze{\char`\e}
    SomeText
  }

or


  {\let\z\edef
    \catcode`e=\active
    \ze{\stringe}
    SomeText
  }
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12):

An `\expandafter` before `\active` tokenizes the following `\def` without the changed category code of `e`:

```
  {
    \catcode`e=\expandafter\active
    \def e{\char`e}
    SomeText
  }
```

Another trick works via `\lowercase`. The definition is done with the active `~` that is changed via `\lowercase` to `e`. Afterwords the category code is changed.

```
  {
    \begingroup
      \lccode`~=`e %
    \lowercase{\endgroup
      \def~%
    }{\char`e}%
    \catcode`e=\active
    SomeText
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

Exploit a benign effect of the “missing space syndrome“:

```
{\catcode`e=13\def e{-\char`\e-}Test}Test\bye
```

[image]

With an abstraction:

```
\def\defactive#1#2{%
  \begingroup
  \lccode`~=`#1\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{#2}%
  \catcode`#1=\active
}

{\defactive{e}{-e-}Test}Test

\bye
```